# Configuring HP Proliant iLO using hponcfg

Tags: ip, dhcp, hp-proliant, ilo

I am configuring an iLO using hponcfg by logging into the machine remotely and running hponcfg with scripts Mod_Directory.xml and then with Mod_Network.xml. I am enabling the DHCP on the device. But after the above scripts are executed successfully and upon rebooting the iLO, it shows the IP address to be 0.0.0.0.
What is missing here, so that the iLO gets an IP from DHCP automatically after configuration?

Comment: What server model? What ILO version?

Comment: The server model is ProLiant DL380 G5. It is iLO 2. I am facing the same problem on other servers too. Am i missing some other script that is to be executed?